# Send an automatic message on each client listed in the comboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, client-server

I have a client server program. Once the client connects to the server, the client's IPAddress is stored into a combobox. If I want to send a message(using a button) to a client, I just need to select a certain IPAdress and send my message. That is just for testing.

My main purpose is I want to send the same message(automatically) to every client inside the comboBox once they connect to the server. How can I make the server send a message to those client? Also checks if someone new connects and then automatically send the same message.

This is where the same message will be sent automatically.

```
public void sendToClient() 
    {
        try
        {
          for(int i = 0; i < myComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                //string value = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[i]);
                sendData(openedFile.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            output.Text += "Error.....\n " + ex.StackTrace;

        }
    }
```

And then the sendData() function

```
private void sendData(String data)
        {
            IPAddress ipep = IPAddress.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipept = new IPEndPoint(ipep, hostPort);
            NetworkStream nStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding asciidata = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] buffer = asciidata.GetBytes(data);
            if (nStream.CanWrite)
            {
                nStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                nStream.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you may do the following:

1) Call SendData using a different Thread. You will achieve more performance and less delay (see below).

2) I believe you may detect WHERE EXACTLY you add the IP into combobox to make the above call - it´s more efficient than inspect the whole IP´s in combobox, all the time.  For instance:

```
  '  At some point of MODULE or top of form
  dim ListOfIPS as List(of String)

  '  At new connection event
  ListOFIPs.Add(IPNumber)
  Dim MyThread As Thread = New Thread(CType(Sub() SendData(IPNumber, MyCustomMessage), ThreadStart))
            MyThread.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.MTA)
            MyThread.Start()
```

3) And, if you really need to send a message to ALL guys connected, you may try something like:

```
  for each Guy as String in ListOfIPS
            Dim MyThread As Thread = New Thread(CType(Sub() SendData(Guy, MyCustomMessage), ThreadStart))
            MyThread.IsBackground = False
            MyThread.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.MTA)
            MyThread.Start()
  next
```

4) If you see the LIST(of T) help, you will find how locate and delete (or just make it blank string) some IP whenever it disconnects...